# Prove that the closed interval [a, b] is compact.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers

I am studying the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ and I want to prove that the closed interval $[a,b]$ is compact using the Heine-Borel Theorem that a set in $\mathbb{R}$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded.

To show that it is closed, I take the complement $(-\infty, a) \bigcup (b, +\infty)$ and show that this is an open set. To show that it is bounded, I assume an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $a- \epsilon < a < x$, for all $x \in [a,b]$ and $b + \epsilon > b> x$, for all $x \in [a,b]$ and this implies that $[a,b]$ is bounded.

If this is correct, is there a more concise or elegant way of proving this?

Answer (score 1):

The first part sounds good to me.

If you are interested in proving it is bounded, you can show it as follows:
\begin{align*}
x\in[a,b] & \Rightarrow a\leq x\leq b \Rightarrow -\max\{|a|,|b|\}\leq a \leq x \leq b\leq\max\{|a|,|b|\} \Rightarrow x\in[-M,M]
\end{align*}
whence we deduce that $[a,b]\subseteq[-M,M]$, where $M = \max\{|a|,|b|\}$.

Hopefully this helps!